# c++ taking the address of a temporary object

Tags: c++

I have two code segments which I expected the same outcome:

First one:

```
SomeClass somefunc(...){
    SomeClass newObj;
    //some codes modify this object
    return newObj;
}

int main(){
    SomeClass *p;
    p = &(somefuc(...));
}
```

Second one:

```
SomeClass *somefunc(...){
    SomeClass newObj;
    //some codes modify this object
    return &newObj;
}

int main(){
    SomeClass *p;
    p = somefunc(...);
}
```

Why is it I got a "taking the address of a temporary object" error when I tried to build the first code segment, while the second code segment doesn't produce an error?

Comment: please show your actual code.

Comment: Neither fragment compiles. The second because you try to return `SomeClass*` from the function declared to return `SomeClass`. Note also that `newObj` is not a temporary - it's a named variable. There is no problem taking its address - the problem lies in *using* said address after the variable's lifetime ends.

Comment: the second example shouldn't even compile, and also `p = &(somefuc(...));` shouldn't compile as you cannot take the address of a rvalue

Comment: @BaummitAugen That problem is definitely present (in the second example), but not related to the question at hand (in the first example). Not a duplicate.

Comment: I guess you meant `SomeClass *somefunc(...){` in your second example?

Comment: maybe this question can be concluded as: the 'newObj' object is still in memory before main method ends, but why I cannot get the address of 'newObj' outside the 'someFunc' function ?

Comment: If that's your question, then Baum mit Augen's duplicate link answers it.

Comment: Then edit your question.

Comment: @rickie pick the function you *want* to use, and ask about it. One of these is evil on the callee side (the second), while the other is evil on the caller side (the first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet does rightfully not compile because, as the compiler said, you cannot take the address of a temporary object because it would be destroyed at the end of the expression (here: the assignment). Thus, saving its address would be meaningless.

The second snippet does compile, **but is still incorrect although it might seem to work**  for the reasons stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) (at least if you try to access the object through the pointer).

Answer (score 4):

Before you even think about this, you need to learn the rules of temporary lifetime.

The broad case is that a temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full-expression creating it.  The implication is that if

```
SomeClass *p;
p = &(somefunc(...));
```

were allowed to work, `p` would be a dangling pointer, targeting an object that no longer exists.

The big exception to the above rule is that when a reference with automatic lifetime is **directly** bound to the temporary object, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to be equal to the lifetime of the reference.  Note that this does not cover `const T& make_lvalue(const T& t) { return t; }` because the reference isn't binding directly, nor class member references.

There are a few cases which are completely safe, in which the address of the temporary is only used immediately and not stored for later.  e.g.

```
memcpy(buffer, &f(), sizeof(decltype(f())));
```

Of course, this results in the "address of a temporary" error you're encountered, but in C++11 and C++14, you can work around it via

```
memcpy(buffer, std::addressof(f()), sizeof(decltype(f())));
```

But do NOT store the resulting pointer.

Comment: Ben is this `std::addressof(f())` guaranteed to be valid by the standard if used immediately in the function? Sorry for beating a dead horse.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even work: https://godbolt.org/z/q5bP6eY54. Because `std::addressof(const T&&)` is deleted. Ref: https://rb.gy/hmakb

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade: That changed two years after this answer was written.  Will edit in the versions of C++ for which the hacky workaround is accepted.

Comment: Your first comment I think is adequately explained by the second paragraph -- the temporary will exist, and its address will be valid, only within the same statement.

Comment: Is that because it is part of the [full-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Full-expressions)? I am asking because my other solution with the `ptr` wrapper works, but I don't know if I am potentially shooting myself in the foot

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade: Yes, your `ptr` workaround is fine for the same reasons that `std::addressof` used to be ok in my `memcpy` example.  The full expression consists of a function call expression, so the entire called function executes within "the lifetime of that expression" (which is a made-up concept) and therefore also within the lifetime of the temporary objects (which is what the Standard concerns itself with).

Answer (score 0):

The first example does not compile because somefunc returns a value, and you attempt to take the address of this temporary thing it returns.  This would work:

```
Someclass* p;
Someclass  val = somefunc (...);
p = &val;
```

The second example does not compile -- or shouldn't -- because somefunc is supposed to return a Someclass, but instead it returns a pointer to a Someclass.  Make it return Someclass* and then it should compile -- but now you're returning a pointer to a local variable, which no longer exists after you leave the function.  Best solution is the first example, as patched here.

Comment: The second example... "should work" What?  It returns a dangling pointer, absolutely useless.  You'd be better off returning `void`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I have edited my answer to say this.